# Get cancelled xhr Status in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am making xmlhttprequest to server to get data, I am getting the data successfully, But i want to get the status if my server gets failed or shutdown unexpectedly. I have the Below code from which i am making a xmlhttprequest.

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", usersResponse);
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.open("GET", CONFIG.api_url + `/api/users`);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
  xhr.send();

  function userResponse(){
  if(this.status===200){
    console.log(this.response);
  }else{
    alert('something went wrong');
  }
```

can anyone please tell the any method, which can be used to get the server error response.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed, Just add

```
xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
```

when making the xhr request & in transferFailed function, you will get this.response is null like below,

```
function transferFailed(){
   console.log(this);
}
```